# How to deploy VB.Net project with Microsoft Report Viewer (rdlc)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have created a VB.Net program with **rdlc reports** and on the development machine it works fine but when i deploy my application to another machine the forms with reportviewer can not be opened and cause the cause the whole application to "**Not responding**" (Stop working), So anyone with the tips of how to deploy the project with rdlc report can help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thank you all, i referenced all **the correct version of Reportviewer dlls** because the application project in my visual studio (**Development machine**) is calling (referencing) the different version with the client machine's Reportviewer (GAC_MISL) which caused the whole application to freeze up!

Now it works !